# Regex - Python - Matching a dir to naming pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match directories name with certain patterns.

I have known values. Select the directory if the first two or three levels match, and if the next levels have any of the good values in any order.

```
known_good = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']
other_known_good = ['dir4', 'dir5']

know_beginning= ['/a/b/', '/a/b/c']

example1 = '/a/b/dir1/dir4/dir5'
example1 = '/b/a/dir4/dir5'
list_dir = [example1, example2]

for dir in list_dir:
    if valid(dir):
        print True
    else:
        print False

example1 --> True
example2 --> False
```

Comment: You'll need to be a little clearer in describing what you are WANTING to happen and what is ACTUALLY happening. Right now you have documentation of (presumably) the current state of your code but no question.

Comment: Since order doesn't matter then how would I use regex to accomplish this or would I have to iterate to check each value instead of regex?

Comment: This code isn't `python`, pls post a MCVE

Answer (score 0):

The irregularity in `know_beginning`, where one item ends with a slash and the other one without it, seems really weird -- is it accidental, as no doubt are the lack of quotes and the repetition of name `example1` (vs using `example2` the second time).  And why are `known_good`and `other_known_good` two separate lists -- is there any significance to that?

Ignoring all these anomalies, and certain or likely errors:

```
start = '(' + '|'.join(know_beginning) + ')'
next = '(/(' + '|'.join(known_good + other_known_good) + '))+'
repat = start + next
```

(this assumes the `/` at the end of some but not all the items in `know_beginning` is accidental and has been removed).

E.g, in your example (with that hopefully-stray / removed:-) it would be

```
(/a/b|/a/b/c)(/(dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4|dir5))+
```

i.e, one of the "beginnings", then, one or more times, slash followed by one of the acceptable "known good" thingies from either of those lists.

Here I'm using plain parentheses just for readability, but they also form matching groups.  If the latter's a problem, replace each plain `(` with `(?:`.